# How to generate UIviews in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm very new to Xcode and programming in general. I have made my first app, submitted it and to be terribly honest it crashed and burned.

Onwards I go. I am now interested in just creating a basic reminders app so that I can teach myself a little bit more. What I mainly don't get is how you can take a main  user input questionnaire framework (e.g. Name: X, Time: X, Date: X), save it and generate another UIView with this information?

Thank you in advance.

-S

Comment: Your question might be far too broad to get any helpful answer here. It sounds like you should just try some tutorials to start with...

Comment: If you're new to programming in general, it might be best just keeping your apps to yourself/your friends for a while. Not every app needs to be submitted to a store, especially if they're just tinkering projects.

Comment: You need to start on basic stuff and earn more skills by practicing. Learn how the fundamentals work. Best place in my experience is apple sample codes. Here is a link to apple startup simple sample projects. Look at this todo project sample code. It is a great place to learn. I thought myself how to code in obj c, so I know where you're going. Anyway, here is the link..https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create this with the latest technology you can create a project with a storyboard.

Add labels for Name, Time, Date and position them in the view of your choice in your storyboard.

Add a UITextField for each label. Use the cntrl + drag technique from your storyboard to your class.

To do this open the Assistant editor. [image]

Make sure the correct class file is open on the right panel. (you can get this by choosing the automatic options)

[image]

cntrl + drag from each textField either to your associated class's .h or the private properties in the .m

Once you have these IBOutlets connected, add the textField Delegate protocol to the .h file.

Implement the delegate methods, there are many tutorials on using UITextFields.

Create a Questionnaire Class with the 3 properties. Initialise a questionnaire object and assign the associated textfield.text strings to the object's properties.

Then you can pass that Questionnaire object to whatever viewController you like and access the properties to use the string data.

Be sure to use copy for strings, this stops modifications to a string from effecting newly assigned strings. (as not copying will be a pointer to a pointer(which can change or even end up pointing to another valid object due to memory reuse by the OS, causing unrecognisedSelector crashes), rather than a pointer to the copied data location)

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSSString *someString;
```